# With VS2008 + ASP.NET, is there a way to perform a clever "Publish"?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, deployment, publish

By clever, I mean NOT TO upload once again the files that has been already uploaded (with the same dates, size or checksum...). It would be great, because the Publish method takes a lot of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the "Replace matching files with local copies" option then the FTP Publish function in VS should only upload files that are different to the server copy.

In other words, VS08 should already be 'clever' publishing your site.

Comment: In fact, even if I do 2 consecutive "Publish", the time it takes is almost the same (apparently it's a little faster, I admit). Possibly it's because I use an Linux server to host the website. I was wondering if a more powerful tool was available to do this, with an ProgressBar by example, it would be nice!

Comment: FTP is inherently slow. If another tool used something other than FTP then it would prob be great. But if your host only supports FTP, then i'd say most all FTP-based tools will be slow like this. I face the same problems too. I hate how slow the publish is. Get a faster net (upload) connection.